# A functional series for the exponential function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, exponential-function

> Show that there is a sequence $(a_{n})$ such that $$e^z=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}{\sin(z^n)} ,|z|\le1 ,z$$ is a complex number.

We know that many functions as $f$ can be represented as $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}{\sin(nx)}$$ I consider $x^n$ instead of $nx$.

I am searching functions as $f$ and $g$ such that :$$g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}{f(z^n)}$$

Answer (score 3):

We are given the power series
$$ f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k z^k$$
where $\,b_1\ne 0\,$ and
$$ g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^n=
\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_jf(z^j)$$
which is always possible since the
$\,\{f(z^j)\}\,$ have leading term
$\,b_1z^j\,$.
Now, $$g(z)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k z^{jk}\right)=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{n=jk}a_jb_k\right)z^n.$$
Thus, $\,c_n = \sum_{n=jk}a_jb_k.\,$ Given
$\,\{b_n\}\,$ and $\,\{c_n\}\,$ we need to
solve for $\,\{a_n\}.\,$ For example,
$$ a_1 = \frac{c_1}{b_1},\;\;
a_2 = \frac{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}{b_1^2},\;\;
a_3 = \frac{b_1c_3-b_3c_1}{b_1^2}.$$
It seems that the solution for $\,a_n\,$ has
denominator $\,b_1^{A073093(n)}\,$ where
[OEIS sequence A073093](https://oeis.org/A073093) is "Number of prime power divisors of n". The numerator is a linear combination of
$\,c_d\,$ where $\,d\,$ divides $\,n\,$
multiplied by powers of $\,b_k\,$ with an
integer coefficient. I don't find a simple
pattern.

In your question, $\,g(z)=e^z-1\,$ and $\,f(z)=\sin(z).\,$ We have
$$g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}z^n\;\;
\text{ and }\;\;
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}
z^{2n+1}.$$
Solve for the $\,\{a_n\}\,$ coefficients to get
$$ \{a_n\}\!=\! 
\frac1{1!},\frac1{2!},\frac2{3!},\frac1{4!},
\frac0{5!},\frac{61}{6!},
\frac2{7!},\frac1{8!},\frac{20160}{9!},
\frac{-15119}{10!},\dots $$
and I don't find any simple pattern.

Comment: What are the coefficients for the exponential function?

Comment: Very nice @Somos.

Comment: Your method is good but if z=1 then you see that the series of a_{n} must be convergent . So you must show that the series is convergence. Thank you.

Comment: @alireza The power series for $\,e^z-1\,$ and $\,\sin(z)\,$ around $\,z=0\,$ have radius of convergence infinity. I don't know what the convergence of original series is.

Comment: You obtained the Coefficients $a_{n}$ as a formal power(Dirichlet) series and the equality you obtained is formal. So you must show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{n}}$ is absolut convergence to show that the equality is real, and is not formal. As you see in the first equality this series is a convergence if z=1 for example.